# Example of custom setDropDownViewResource spinner item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-widget

I would like to display two values in an drop down  view of my spinner.

Currently, it only has a city name, but I would also like to add a small distance field to it.

```
    MyCity<MyCityDistance> dataAdapter;  

    dataAdapter = new MyCity(this, R.layout.mycityrow, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

I have all the code for custom data adapter, exapanding my view and holder etc.

However, the item which gets show doesn't display both the city and its distance from my current location.

It only shows what is overridden in toString() method of MyCityDistance class.

I even tried setting

`dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.mycityrow);`

but, no success. It throws an error.

```
04-02 11:05:22.600: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
04-02 11:05:22.600: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
04-02 11:05:22.600: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
04-02 11:05:22.600: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:332)
```

What is a good example of creating your own custom `setDropDownViewResource()`?

Even if I comment out the `setDropDownViewResource()` line, I get the same error.

Note: The only effect `mycityrow` current is that the first element of Spinner is show as per the layout of `mycityrow`. However, when I click open the drop down, that layout is lost. I want the same layout during drop down selection too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note the below example uses the inbuilt `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`, Unfortunately the text color will probably be the same as the background. You can simply solve this by creating your own custom view and use it in the adapter instead.

Let me know if i should explain any part of it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    class City {
        public City(String city, int d) {
            this.city = city;
            this.distance = String.valueOf(d);
        }

        String city;
        String distance;
    }

    class CityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<City> {

        public CityAdapter(Context context, List<City> objects) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, objects);
        }

        @Override //don't override if you don't want the default spinner to be a two line view
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return initView(position, convertView);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
            return initView(position, convertView);
        }

        private View initView(int position, View convertView) {
            if(convertView == null)
                convertView = View.inflate(getContext(),
                                           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                           null);
            TextView tvText1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            TextView tvText2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            tvText1.setText(getItem(position).city);
            tvText2.setText(getItem(position).distance);
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        List<City> list = new ArrayList<MainActivity.City>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            list.add(new City(String.format("City %d", i + 1), (i + 1) * 1000));
        spinner.setAdapter(new CityAdapter(this, list));

    }

}
```

Comment: Passing the parent as null is equivalent to passing `attachToRoot` as false when inflated using the LayoutInflater.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this nice solution. I've got one question to you: Why do I need to override the getView() and the getDropDownView()? Why does it not work when I only override the getDropDownView()?

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting the line dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource() and the adapter will try to use the mycityow layout file for the drop down as well. Works in simple cases.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that approach earlier, update my question now.