# Android spinner showing object reference instead of string

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Ok so I am having a issue with my spinner. Its being populated with data pulled from a webservice. The issue im having is that when the spinner is not clicked instead of showing the string for the first item in the spinner its showing an object reference for it instead.

I have looked at related question but still couldn't see what im missing, is it as simple as missing a toString reference?

Here is the code for populating the spinner

```
private void buildDrinkDropDown() {

        List<NameValuePair> apiParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        apiParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("call", "drinkList"));

        bgt = new BackGroundTask(MAP_API_URL, "GET", apiParams);

        try {

            JSONArray drinks = bgt.execute().get();

            for (int i = 0; i < drinks.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject d = drinks.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = d.getString(TAG_ID_DRINK);
                String createdAt = d.getString(TAG_CREATED_AT);
                String updatedAt = d.getString(TAG_UPDATED_AT);
                String price = d.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                String name = d.getString(TAG_NAME);

                drinkList.add(new Drink( createdAt ,id, name, price,updatedAt ));
            }

            drinkField = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.countryField); 
            DrinkAdapter dAdapter = new DrinkAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, drinkList);
            drinkField.setAdapter(dAdapter);

            drinkField.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //Drink selectedDrink = drinkList.get(position);
                    GlobalDrinkSelected = drinkList.get(position).getId().toString();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}


            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the adapter class

```
package com.android.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrinkAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Drink>
{
    private Activity context;
    ArrayList<Drink> data = null;

    public DrinkAdapter(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<Drink> data)
    {
        super(context, resource, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {   // Ordinary view in Spinner, we use android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);   
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {   // This view starts when we click the spinner.
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdown_value_id, parent, false);
        }

        Drink item = data.get(position);
        String test = item.getName();
        Log.d("test ", test);

        if(item != null)
        {   

            TextView drinkName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_value);

            if(drinkName != null){
             drinkName.setText(item.getName());
             Log.d("find me ", drinkName.toString());
            }

        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Here is the xml for dropdown_value_id layout thats used in the adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If any more information is needed just shout.

Any help would be greatly apprieciated

Edit: Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of spinner]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My quick thought: getView() method is used to represent the row. Can you implement similar coding like getDropDownView method into getView() method also.

**Copy past the content from getDropDownView method into getView() method**

I didnt tried this, but I had done similar one in ListView where I did similar coding in getView() method.

I will also try to replicate this locally and post if I find anything.

Comment: No luck, it must be getting that reference from the getDropDownView method... I just cant figure out how to change it to a string

Comment: I just realised i did exactly what you told me to do apologies!

Comment: I did it my way....

`@Override

public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

return getView(position, convertView, parent);

}`

Comment: I tried as given answer but still in the drop-down list I'm getting object reference instead of string. Any suggestion??

Answer (score 24):

I was having a similar issue, however I was using the default ArrayAdapter without extending it in a separate class. After looking into it a little bit, I found this:

> However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the toString() of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects. Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

The default ArrayAdapter will call .toString() on each object in the array that has been passed to the Adapter. If your DrinkAdapter does nothing more than display the name of the Drink, you can override the toString() method and be finished

Adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<Drink> drinkAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Drink>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, drinks);
```

Class Object:

```
public Drink {

    String name;

    // Constructor, getters, and setters for the object here

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName(); // You can add anything else like maybe getDrinkType()
    }
}
```

And you're done, no need to make a separate class for your DrinkAdapter

Comment: How you can add + ToString1,ToString2,ToString3 ?

Comment: My solution is so bad, createObjet2(same ob1) toString()

Comment: @delive I'm not sure what you're attempting to do, could you be a little more clear? If you're trying to put together a list of items in the return string, i would recommend using a StringBuilder class. After declaring a `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();` you can append to it. `builder.append(Item1: ") + append(item1.toString()).append(" Item 2: ").append(item2.toString()).toString()` and it will give you the string `"Item1: value Item2: value"`

Comment: I have a object that I need show 2 values, for example  obj.getName , obj.getSurname

Comment: Solved : in toString return getName() + " " + getSurname

Comment: I have 3 items(text, text, image) in the list so how to manage it from toString() in the viewing list?

Comment: @A.R. if you're doing more than just a single line of text then you won't be able to leverage `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`. You'll need to make your own custom Adapter with a different layout

Answer (score 7):

Ok so i solved this by doing a little more research and looking at the answer to this question [Example of custom setDropDownViewResource spinner item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970675/example-of-custom-setdropdownviewresource-spinner-item)

I extracted what i was doing in getDropDownView and called it in both getView and getDropDownView.

here is the code

```
package com.android.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrinkAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Drink>
{
    private Activity context;
    ArrayList<Drink> data = null;

    public DrinkAdapter(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<Drink> data)
    {
        super(context, resource, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {   // Ordinary view in Spinner, we use android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

        return initView(position, convertView, parent);  
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {   // This view starts when we click the spinner.
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdown_value_id, parent, false);
        }

        Drink item = data.get(position);
        String test = item.getName();
        Log.d("test ", test);

        if(item != null)
        {   

            TextView drinkName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_value);

            if(drinkName != null){
             drinkName.setText(item.getName());
             Log.d("find me ", drinkName.toString());
            }

        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. This is nice. Love the logic behind it

Comment: In class define your Object, you add this line to the class

Answer (score 4):

In your class define Object to show in ListView, you add example line of code below

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getComment();
}
```

It word for me .