# How to set properly the values of a list or adapter in a spinner in Android?

Tags: android, json, list, android-spinner

I have the follow JSON

```
[
{
    "Codigo": "101"
},
{
    "Codigo": "111"
},
{
    "Codigo": "117"
}
]
```

And I have 2 code to set values in a `Spinner` but not one work

**First code**

Using a list to set the value in a Spinner

```
JSONObject myjson;
        JSONArray the_json_array;
        try {
            myjson = new JSONObject(myJson);
            the_json_array = myjson.getJSONArray("Codigo");
            List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < the_json_array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject another_json_object = the_json_array.getJSONObject(i);

                list.add(String.valueOf(another_json_object));
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FormularioCompletoActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                clasificacion.setAdapter(dataAdapter);              

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I code doens't set the value of the list in the spinner, the spinner is null, without data

**Second code**

In this part I use `Gson` and `TypeToken` with own adapter to set the value.

```
List<ClasificacionModel> list;
        Type happyCollection = new TypeToken<Collection<ClasificacionModel>>() {}.getType();
        list =  new Gson().fromJson(myJSon, happyCollection);

        _adapter = new ClasificacionAdapter(FormularioCompletoActivity.this, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, list);
        _adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        clasificacion.setAdapter(_adapter);
```

Xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/clasificacion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Model

```
public class ClasificacionModel {

public String Codigo;

public String getCodigo() {
    return Codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    Codigo = codigo;
}
}
```

but this happen

[image]

Comment: Can you post your Custom Adapter??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `toString()` in your `ClasificacionModel`

Example using gson

```
public class ClasificacionModel {

public String Codigo;

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Codigo;
}

}
```

Then

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourspinnerid);
List<ClasificacionModel> list;
Type happyCollection = new TypeToken<Collection<ClasificacionModel>>() {}.getType();
list =  new Gson().fromJson(myjson, happyCollection);
ArrayAdapter<ClasificacionModel> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ClasificacionModel>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

The above uses a `ArrayAdapter`. You can use a Custom ArrayAdapter if you need to.

Snap

[image]

Your First Method is wrong

```
  myjson = new JSONObject(myJson);
```

Your json is a `JSONArray`

Comment: Thank you very much, how do you know that... overdrive that method??

Comment: @zhelon read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776661/android-spinner-showing-object-reference-instead-of-string