# spinner dropdown view show reference

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, custom-adapter

I tried this answer
[Android spinner showing object reference instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776661/android-spinner-showing-object-reference-instead-of-string/15776859#15776859)
but didn't work for me.

I'm using `'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'` library

I'm facing an issue regarding `spinnerdropdown`.
I made `CustomAdapter` for spinner but in `dropdownview` it shows reference
like

> spinneritems@f1312a01

Here is my Adapter code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItems> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Activity context;

    private List<SpinnerItems> spinnerItemsList;


    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, @LayoutRes int resource,List<SpinnerItems> spinnerItemsList) {
        super(context, resource,spinnerItemsList);
        this.context=context;

        this.spinnerItemsList=spinnerItemsList;

        //inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_item_spiner, parent, false);
        }
        SpinnerItems spinnerItems=spinnerItemsList.get(position);
        String name=spinnerItems.getName();
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnertitle);
        label.setText(spinnerItemsList.get(position).getName());

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        Log.d("drop","drp");
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_item_spiner, parent, false);

        SpinnerItems spinnerItems=spinnerItemsList.get(position);
        String name=spinnerItems.getName();
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnertitle);
        label.setText(spinnerItemsList.get(position).getName());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(spinnerItems),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return  row;
    }


}
```

I printed `Toast` and Log in `dropdown` but it seems that it doesn't go into `getdropdownview` method

here is main class:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                SpinnerItems spinnerItems=new SpinnerItems(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),response.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                cityList.add(spinnerItems);
            }
            cityAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.simple_item_spiner,cityList);
            city.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
```

Comment: you should see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15776859/6630837

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android spinner showing object reference instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776661/android-spinner-showing-object-reference-instead-of-string)

Comment: @SudheeshR please check my code. i tried that code :) but didn't work for me

Comment: @Nilu its not duplicate .. i tried his code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
SpinnerItems spinnerItems=spinnerItemsList.get(position);
```

Use getItemAtPosition(position):

```
SpinnerItems spinnerItems=spinnerItemsList.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: Hope this works. Please dont forget to mark it as answer if it works for you :)

Comment: sure. i'll try but i think its seems it does not go into getdropdown function. well i'm testing your answer

Comment: not working. doesn't find this method. as its arrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```html
Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(spinnerItems),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Use this ..

```html
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(name),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: this is adapter bro! its not solution btw. i also printed log

Comment: so what is the issue? Is it that there are no items printed in dropdown or you can't select any items in the dropdown?

Comment: issue is dropdownview shows object reference, not exactly name. because i'm using library and in library they are using listview. getview is working fine but in my custom adapter, dropdown not working