# Get reference to a Spinner in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-spinner

`findViewById()` works fine when you need to find something any UI element that is in your layout. However, using the second option of this answer [How to add a Dropdown item on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar), I added a `Spinner` to my `ActionBar`.

Now the problem I am facing is how to retrieve a reference to this `Spinner` so that I can change the font that it uses. **How do I do that?**

My **menu/sort_spinner** looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/sort" 
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/sort"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_spinner"/>
</menu>
```

and **layout/actionbar_spinner** like this:

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:entries="@array/type" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in the `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sort_spinner, menu);
    MenuItem spinnerItem = menu.findItem(R.id.sort);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)spinnerItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    //Your rest of code...
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: and the `Typeface`? I am not using a custom adapter :)

Comment: are you sure about the `findItem(R.id.sort)`? Are you sure it shouldn't be `R.id.spinner`?

Comment: You are assigning a MenuItem to a spinner.

Comment: @user3249477 Yeah, I had that nagging feeling that something isnt right :)

Comment: Sorry, I didnt read the question fully and made a silly mistake in the code. I didn't try this out, but it should work. Updated the code. Please check. :)

Comment: @LittleChild Sorry, but as far as I know for changing the Typeface you will have to use custom adapter for the spinner. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150588/android-spinner-change-font-typeface/19150605#19150605

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your `onCreateOptionsMenu` you can save a global reference of your menu like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_items, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

To change the Font you will however have to use an adapter. Here's an example that *should* work.

```
MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(R.id.sort);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);

MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public TextView getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        v.setTypeface(myFont);
        return v;
    }

    public TextView getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView v = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        v.setTypeface(myFont);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: and now for the `Typeface` for the text inside the spinner. How to? :)

Comment: No way to avoid the adapter ? :)

Comment: I am afraid not. You have to set the Typeface for the TextView and that cannot be done unless you make a custom adapter.

Comment: @LittleChild what do you need the spinner for, if you're not planning to use an adapter? How else would you populate it then?

Comment: @user3249477 I think he was actually speaking about custom adapter. If needed he can simply populate it using an `ArrayAdapter`. No need to customise. But for setting `TypeFace` he will definitely need to customise it.

Comment: @user3249477 using a string array straight from the XML using `android:entries="@array/something"`

Comment: @LittleChild You do know that you can still use the xml array with the custom adapter?